# Pairing list of data frames with list of chraracters

Tags: r, list, dataframe, vector

I have a list of data frames

```
df1=data.frame(yield=c(7,4,8),temp=c(25,28,30)) 
df2=data.frame(yield=c(6,5,8),temp=c(26,25,26))
df3=data.frame(yield=c(3,4,7),temp=c(31,28,27)) 

l1=list(df1,df2,df3)
```

and a list of characters

```
l2=list("high N","mid N","low N")
```

I'm trying to make a variable called "trt" in each dataframe populating it with  each element of the character list.

On one dataframe it would look like:

```
df1$trt=l2[[1]]
```

but when I try to make a lapply of it, I cant quite get what I'm looking for.

I tried:

```
l3=lapply(l1,function(x) x$trt=l2)
```

and

```
l3=lapply(l1,function(x,y) x$trt=l2[[y]])
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe `mapply(function(i,j) {i$trt <- j; i},i = l1,j = l2,SIMPLIFY = F)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirly sure about your expected but try `Map`

```
Map(`[<-`, l1, i = "trt", value = l2)
  yield temp    trt
1     7   25 high N
2     4   28 high N
3     8   30 high N

[[2]]
  yield temp   trt
1     6   26 mid N
2     5   25 mid N
3     8   26 mid N

[[3]]
  yield temp   trt
1     3   31 low N
2     4   28 low N
3     7   27 low N
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't entirely clear about my expected result. Yes, you got it right! What does the '[<-]' do in your function? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Or use `transform`

```
Map(transform, l1, trt = l2)
#[[1]]
#  yield temp    trt
#1     7   25 high N
#2     4   28 high N
#3     8   30 high N

#[[2]]
#  yield temp   trt
#1     6   26 mid N
#2     5   25 mid N
#3     8   26 mid N

#[[3]]
#  yield temp   trt
#1     3   31 low N
#2     4   28 low N
#3     7   27 low N
```

---

With `tidyverse`, we can use `mutate`

```
library(tidyverse)
map2(l1, l2, ~ .x %>% 
                   mutate(trt = .y))
```